# Magento Core API: XML-RPC Error adding tracking number

Tags: xml, api, xml-rpc

I'm looking for suggestions on troubleshooting the error "100 -     Requested shipment not exists. " when I use sales_order_shipment.addTrack to send tracking updates to Magento. I'm currently using vbscript and XML to post via XML-RPC calls.  I'm able to query and parse shipment info for import without issue.  The problem occurs when I attempt to write tracking back.

During the export I use the steps below.
1. I'm able to successful create a  shipment 1st and obtain the shipment increment id using sales_order_shipment.create

1. When I transmit the command sales_order_shipment.addTrack I receive an XML fault message back
2. I have verified the increment id

Comment: can you shows bite of your code??